# Is this network able to be interpreted as a node and apply KCL?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, kirchhoffs-laws

I've may been asking the really trivial question.
[image]

Is above diagram correct?

I interpreted the network as a node and applied KCL.

No such grounded thing is included in the network.

Comment: yes, your calculation of I' is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A network that has wires could be considered a transmission line and therefore the lumped element models that underpin Kirchhoff's current and voltage laws may be invalidated or [limited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Limitations), If they are not invalidated then your solution is correct. Limitations: -

[image]

Comment: Is this from Wikipedia? You should credit it. Also, it is incorrect. KCL applies even when charge accumulates in a circuit, if one uses Maxwell's definition of current. (I.e. includes displacement current as well as conduction current -- fyi displacement current induces magnetic fields, so it is "real" current.) Thus, KCL applies to current flowing through a capacitor. Similarly, KVL applies with the assumption that an induced emf is not induced at a point, but in a loop. Then, KVL is true, even if there is an external time-varying magnetic field.

Comment: I have credited it a little bit higher - the word "limited" is linked to that wiki page.